# .Net 4.5 assembly registration by 2.0

Tags: c#, .net

Planning to migrate few assemblies to .Net framework 4.5. For registration, we are now using RegAsm.exe from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
After migrating to .Net FW 4.5, can we still use the RegAsm from the above path or should we use the one from v4.0.30319 or any other v4.x folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `v4.0.30319` version of `regasm.exe` for .NET 4.0+

32-bit: `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe`

64-bit: `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe`

Comment: Thank you @Alex Wiese. I just wanted to know if the "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727" will still be available in the PC where .Net 4.5 is installed ? Will installing 4.5 assembly file using v2.0.50727 will pose any issues ?

Comment: It won't be available if .NET 2.0/3.0/3.5 is not installed. For a .NET 4.5 assembly file you need to use `v4.0.30319`. For that assembly you will need .NET 4.5 installed, so `v4.0.30319` will be definitely be there.

Comment: Thank you very much @Alex Wiese. Very well appreciated.